# Blogging platform using Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I am planning to make blogging platform using Drupal 7. In which I am going to allow user to create his own site using my subdomain. Is this possible with Drupal 7?

Which modules I am going to need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking at either the core blog module (which isn't that great), or a combination of content types and [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Start [here](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/182) for blog building information!

With regards to the second part, are you looking to have the user create a site, and then start blogging on it?  Wordpress.org style?  For that you'll firstly need to get a solid theme in place, as well as a working blog.  Secondly, look into [Aegir](http://www.aegirproject.org/) which is a REALLY solid, powerful tool for creating Drupal sites off the back of another site (using a site as an installation profile almost...but not quite).

There are a couple of installation/demonstration videos [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Rf_E4dl4zk) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fk6HaXnPMrM&list=UUxlWU3GeyV0L_NzQovPtEPw&index=6&feature=plcp).

Answer (score 0):

Blog as such is a standard content type comes with a core! What you might require though is to maintain different user profiles for which you may need [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

Comment: Blog isn't a standard content type - Blog is a core module.  A pretty bad module module that's being [discontinued in D8](http://drupal.org/node/233301).  Because of this it's probably best NOT to use it.